# mdls on OSX Not reporting UTC Time zone adjustment

Tags: macos, shell

I use the command `mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate $file` to get the content creation date for a file on OS X.

`~/Movies/Unprocessed -> mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate test.txt
kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2014-11-02 22:00:57 +0000`

The output on my system should be:
`kMDItemContentCreationDate = 2014-11-02 18:00:57 -0400`

Finder displays the correct adjusted creation date. If the adjustment isn't stored in the metadata then where is it stored? Where can I get the actual local creation date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kMDItemContentCreationDate` property contains the creation date of the file **in GMT**, not in your system's current time zone. If you want the creation date in your system's local timezone, you'll need to convert it yourself.

One easy way to convert this in a shell script is using `date`:

```
date -f'%F %T %z' -j "$(mdls -raw -name kMDItemContentCreationDate test.txt)"
```

Comment: The command `stat -f %Sc $file` gives the time that the file was created on the file system. `mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate` gives the timestamp for when the **content** was created, the date and time that a video was shot for example. If I copy a MOV file and run  `stat -f %Sc` on both files I get two different dates. `mdls` returns the same results for the original and the copy. The time zone information must be stored somewhere or the timestamp is essentially useless for determining the on location time when the video was shot.

Comment: Oh, interesting. All of the files I looked at had the same values for both. In any case, I've updated my answer with a way to do the conversion.

Comment: As a side note — keep in mind that computers generally store dates (like the content creation date here) as an absolute *point in time*, not as a specific hour/minute/second/timezone. `mdls` is choosing to output this time in GMT, rather than your local time zone, but it's not a "different" time; it's just a different way of representing it.

Comment: Applications like Finder and iPhoto display the the content creation date as the local time where a video was taken for instance. That is what I am trying to do. The actual timezone offset where the content was created must be stored somewhere or these apps wouldn't be able to display it. Converting to my machine's current local time format doesn't solve my problem.  The %Y in the date conversion needs to be %T. Thanks for the answer I'll update when I figure this out.

Comment: After doing some more digging it appears that the way Apps like Finder and iPhoto display content creation time in the manner described is by reading metadata contained in the files themselves. A command line solution using mdls doesn't get you all the way there. For my purposes, I will just stick with the time in GMT.